# How to create rounded border Button using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I need to add border with rounded corner in Button using Jetpack Compose

Like :

[image]

Answer (score 133):

To achieve a button with a border with rounded corners you can use the [**`OutlinedButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#OutlinedButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.material.ButtonElevation,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.material.ButtonColors,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) component applying in the **`shape`** parameter a [**`RoundedCornerShape`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/RoundedCornerShape):

```
OutlinedButton(
    onClick = { },
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(50), // = 50% percent
                                    // or shape = CircleShape
    colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(contentColor = Color.Red)
){
    Text( text = "Save" )
}
```

[image]

It works with M2 and M3.

Comment: Thank you sir , but i want with custom ui with rounded border

Comment: @Sanjayrajsinh the `OutlinedButtonStyle` has rounded corners by default. You can in any case override the value using `shape = RoundedCornerShape(x.dp)`

Comment: @Sanjayrajsinh or using a percent value with `shape = RoundedCornerShape(50)`. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I don't see any difference between Button() and OutlinedButton(). If I use the same code with Button() it will give same result. May I know what's the difference ?

Comment: @RanjithKumar The `OutlinedButton` is a `Button` with an `outlinedBorder` and custom colors as `backgroundColor= MaterialTheme.colors.surface` and  `contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary`

Answer (score 56):

Just use modifier as:

```
modifier = Modifier.border( width = 2.dp,
                            color = Color.Red,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
```

Answer (score 24):

use *Clip* Modifier, plus you can also choose a specific corner to curve

```
 modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(15.dp, 15.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp))
```

Answer (score 18):

Use the `clip` Modifier.

`Modifier.clip(CircleShape)`

Answer (score 7):

This is the button you have in that image :

```
Button(
       onClick = {},
       shape = RoundedCornerShape(23.dp),
       border = BorderStroke(3.dp, Color.Red),
       colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(contentColor = Color.Red, backgroundColor = Color.White)
       ) {
            Text(
                text = "Save",
                fontSize = 17.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 30.dp, vertical = 6.dp)
            )
        }
```

Comment: shape = RoundedCornerShape(23.dp) do the trick in material 3!

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
               Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(40.dp)
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .border(
                            1.dp,
                            Color.RED,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                        )

                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                        text = "Save",
                        color = Color.RED,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                    )
                }
```